Is ordinary renewal process always delayed renewal process?
From the definition, I feel like the ordinary renewal process have additional condition to the first inter-event time as iid, while the delayed renewal process only have the first inter-event time independent of other inter-event times. In that case, can I conclude that the ordinary renewal process is always a delayed renewal process as well?
